# Angular 2: Can't resolve service from my library

Tags: angular

I have 2 angular projects:

- MyLib
- MyApp

I want to use MyLib in MyApp project. MyLib contains library created by angular cli. I built it, installed it and imported MyLibModule into MyAppModule - everything seems ok. Problem is when I use any service from the MyLib in any MyApp component I am getting: **Module not found: Error: Can't resolve..**

Each service in lib module has:

```
@Injectable({providedIn: 'root'})
export class MyLibService {
```

Each component & pipe in MyLib is listed in the export section of the MyLibModule.

Thanx for any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was not having all classes listed in the **public_api.ts**.